# Creating Neo4j nodes with different label in HTTP API

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create two nodes with different label in Neo4j using POSTMAN. Iam able to create with statements but I couldnt create using queries. The following are the nodes and endpoints which I used to create the nodes.

POST: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
JSON:

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "CREATE (case:Case  {props}) RETURN CaseItem",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : {
        "OrderableItemNo" :666666,
        "description":"tiger",
        "status":"lion"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "statement" : "CREATE (Group:Group {props}) RETURN Group",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : {
      "description":"giraffe"
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

It is working fine. I want to create using queries

POST: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node
JSON:

```
{
  "query" : "CREATE (Case:Case {OrderableItemNo:{OrderableItemNo},description:{description},status:{status},SoleSource:{SoleSource}, ePROSuppID:{ePROSuppID},ePROSuppAuxID:{ePROSuppAuxID}}) RETURN Case",
  "params" : { 
     "OrderableItemNo" :666666,
     "description":"rrrrrr",
        "status":"ggggggg",
  },
   "query" : "CREATE (Group:Group {hirerachyCode:{hirerachyCode},description:{description}}) RETURN Group",
  "params" : { 
     "hirerachyCode" :333333,
     "description":"bbbbbb"
  }
  }
```

When I try to send this, the group node is created but the case node is not created.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: WHy are you using two different endpoints for sending cypher queries ? The `/db/data/transaction/commit` is the good one, the one (ie. `node`) is deprecated, and you should not use it.